# Hyper-v Server 2012 standalone server, is it free?

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I know that Hyper-V 2008 is completely free, also i think the same for 2012. But on Microsoft price calculation page, they never mention hyper-v standalone server as free software...

[Calculation page](http://cloudeconomics.cloudapp.net/)

Can anyone that already use confirm this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Hyper-V 2012 Server is free.

[image]